# Azure Storage Container : Access Control (IAM) to a App Registration has a different Object ID than App Registration in AAD

Tags: azure-blob-storage, rbac, azure-service-principal, azure-app-registration

I set up a Storage Container (Blob) and a Role Assignement (Storage Account Contributor) to a App Registration with a client Secret-> so I can query the blob files in a runbook as a service principal. So far so fine. App Registartion has API Permission to Azure Storage and it run fine.

I then wanted to check my error-handling and output of the runbook when permissions are missing and removed the API Permission to Azure Storage on the App Registration. And nothing changed at all...The runbook succesfully created storage context and down-/uploaded the file without problem.

After some digging, I noticed that the object-id of the App Registration is different when I look at it in Access Control (IAM) of the storage container than when I load the object in Azure Active Directory (see pic below). So I thought well there must be some "noise" and removed and re-added the Role Assignement to the container. I then run into the error as expected.

After successfully worked on my error-handling i re-applied the permissions and...the error wont disapear. So I again looked at the objects and again...die object-ids where different. I had to remove the RBAC and re-add it to reflect the permission change. After re-adding still the same issue. I have different ID's.

Does anyone know why thats different? And why wont it reflect the permission change withour remove-re-add?

Thank you!

Storage Container vs AAD:
[image: Storage Container vs AAD]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure AD app registration is backed by 2 directory objects: an application and a service principal. As its name implies, the latter is the principal for authentication/authorization. Thus, you will see 2 object ids.

Regarding the access issue, all the principal (user or service) needs is an [RBAC role assigned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/assign-azure-role-data-access?tabs=portal#assign-an-azure-role), thus adding or removing application permissions won't make a difference.